# Create a Gmail address for a Google account but use another email as the login

Tags: gmail, google-account

I want to add a Gmail address to my account (that I will not use) but I don't want that address to be my main address (i.e. my login) for Google, because I already use me@example.com everywhere.

I don't have Gmail, but do have a Google account on a personal mail address (me@example.com) where I read emails from. When I got an Android phone, I tried to add my Google account, it keeps asking me to create a Gmail address. Without that account, I basically can't do anything with it.

As the Gmail creation form tells me that the Gmail address will become the main address, I'd like to know if/how it's possible to set me@example.com the main address afterwards.

Or, if you know a way to use my Android with my Google Account without Gmail.

Comment: Why do you need your other email to be the "main" account?  You can use secondary accounts for the Market and so on.

Comment: I've read that emails from Android market and other google apps will go to the unused gmail address, which I don't want (I won't read it).

Comment: @Matthieu In my experience the emails go to whichever account you've set the Market and Google Wallet up on. AFAIK the only thing you need an actual GMail account for is GMail, any Google Account will work for settings backup, calendar/contacts sync, Market access, etc. You can then use the normal Email app (or any other from the Market) for your emails.

Comment: @GAThrawn If I can still log in using my own email, and configure it to send Market and Wallet emails on my own address, then that's fine. However without a GMail account, *I can't add my Google Account to Android*, use contacts and calendar sync, Market, etc... I'm not the only one complaining about this apparently :(.